# Get current web folder in Java with Jersey JAX RS.WS

Tags: java, web-services, rest, jax-ws, glassfish-4

This is seems easy enough, but seems like I can't find the answer at Google.
I need to send a list of files at my webroot folder, kind like directory browsing.

I am using Glassfish, and JAX-RS.WS, and genson for POJO writer.

App structure like this:

```
download
|- build
|- dist
|- src
|- web
|  |- files
```

Below is my code

```
@Path("home")
public class HomeResource {

    @Context
    private UriInfo context;

    @GET
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    public String get() {
        return System.getProperty("user.dir"); // ??? Any idea what should be in here?
    }
}
```

And it gave result as :

```
/usr/lib/glassfish/glassfish/domains/domain1/config
```

I need it to point to

```
/sites/download/web/
```

or at least

```
/sites/download/
```

because I need my service to give a list like for example:

```
/files/item.zip
/files/document.pdf
```

Anyone can please help??

Thank you

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can get the [real path](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/servlet/ServletContext.html#getRealPath-java.lang.String-) from the [servlet context](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/servlet/ServletContext.html).

```
package com.scotth.jaxrsrealpath;

import javax.servlet.ServletContext;
import javax.ws.rs.GET;
import javax.ws.rs.Path;
import javax.ws.rs.Produces;
import javax.ws.rs.QueryParam;
import javax.ws.rs.core.Context;
import javax.ws.rs.core.MediaType;

/**
 * @author scotth
 * jax-rs application deployed to /JaxRsRealPath/
 */
@Path("sample")
public class SampleResource {

    @Context ServletContext servletContext;

    @GET
    @Produces(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN)
    public String getHello(@QueryParam("path") String requestedPath) {
        String path = requestedPath == null ? "/" : requestedPath;
        String actualPath = servletContext.getRealPath(path);
        return String.format("Hello, world! \nRequested path: %s\nActual path: %s", path, actualPath);
    }
}
```

Requesting `/JaxRsRealPath/sample?path=/WEB-INF` yields, in my eclipse-managed Tomcat instance, the actual filesystem path to the requested file or folder - usable with `java.io.File`:

```
Hello, world! 
Requested path: /WEB-INF
Actual path: /Users/scotth/Workspaces/eclipse45-default/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.wst.server.core/tmp1/wtpwebapps/JaxRsRealPath/WEB-INF/
```

Another example that just requests `/JaxRsRealPath/sample` (the code then checks the path to context root `/`):

```
Hello, world! 
Requested path: /
Actual path: /Users/scotth/Workspaces/eclipse45-default/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.wst.server.core/tmp1/wtpwebapps/JaxRsRealPath/
```

From there you can use the [File APIs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/File.html) to get directory listings of files if you want.